# How do I count the number of times the buttons click when the page reloads after each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to keep count of the number of times my button is clicked  but the page is relaoded after each click,how can i keep the count?

Comment: What you've tried so far ? This is not the platform where you directly asks for the code.

Comment: A little bit more info please. Where do you want to keep the count. On a server, on the client. Individual for each visiter, global for everyone?

Comment: Or `localStorage/sessionStorage` as per your requirements....

Comment: You can bind a JS function and use AJAX to store the click count somewhere in database

Comment: I am not asking for code, I am asking is there any way to keep track on the number of counts,because whatever approach i have seen DOM is relaoded when button is clicked.
I want to store the counts in the client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML5 `localStorage`:

```
function addClicks() {
    var currentValue = localStorage.getItem('myClicks') ? parseInt(localStorage.getItem('myClicks')) : 0;
    var newValue = currentValue  + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('myClicks', newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store it in localstorage:

```
localStorage.clicks = +(localStorage.clicks || 0) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the count in the cookie and always read and increment the count in the cookie.
The other option could be that if your page is doing a post back then you can store it in a hidden field and then read and increment from the hidden field.

Let me know if you need help in coding. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

On each click of button save the counter value in cookie or local-storage via js or php for first time. There on just increment the counter by accessing cookie or local storage value and update the same for next clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **localstorage**

LocalStorage can only store string values. You can use parseInt which converts a string into an integer. It takes (key, value) pairs.

To set value

```
localstorage.setItem("count", "1");
```

and for each click, increment it like below

```
localstorage.setItem(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('count')) + 1);
```